# How can I get the pixel data from outside the canvas?

Tags: javascript, drawing, pixel, processing.js, khan-academy

In Khan Academy computer programming environment, I can use get(x,y,width,height) to capture the pixel data as an image.

```
var img = get(x,y,width,height);//make a variable that stores the image
```

Then, I can display the image like this: image(img,x,y,width,height);

Is there a way I can retrieve the pixels that would be outside of the screen?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "outside of the screen"? Outside of the web browser window? (No, that would be a big security hazard if that were allowed.) Outside of your devices display? (There aren't any pixels out there to retrieve.) Do you mean something else?

Comment: Yeah, now I think it is impossible. Well, if you had a circle were half of it was outside the canvas, therefore being cut off from view